# Create list that depends on a variable

Tags: python

actually I have a problem because I want to create a list inside a function but it depends on a variable, I mean... with a input I want to define the value of the variable, with the code I simulated the program of a restaurant to serve a table and I should be able to add to the list of each table, the food they ask. This is my code now:

```
foodlist = []
table_1 = []
table_2 = []
table_3 = []
table_4 = []
table_5 = []
table_6 = []
p = 0

def openFile():
    file = open("cartarest.txt","r",1,"utf-8")
    line = file.readline().strip()
    while line != "":    
        parts = line.split(";")
        name = parts[0]
        price = int(parts[1])
        type = parts[2]     
        foodlist.append(parts)
        line = file.readline().strip()
        p += 1
    return (foodlist,p)

def serveTable(x):
    print("The menu of the restaurant is:")
    print(foodlist)
    add = input("Which food do you want to add?: ")
    while add != 0:
        for i in range(p):
            if add.lower() == foodlist[i][0]:
                **table_+x.append(foodlist[i])**
        add = input("Which food do you want to add?: ")

openFile()
tableserve = input("What table do you want to attend?")
while tableserve.lower() != "cerrar":
    serveTable(tableserve)
    tableserve = input("What table do you want to attend?")
```

EDIT: I have solved the problem with the variable 'p' but now I have a question, how to restrict the range of the tables, because i have tried to put a value like "-1" and the code runs normally, it shouldn't work, just with values between 1 and 6(obviously using the answer of @Tim)

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having?

Comment: format file ((name;price;type of food))

Comment: `tables = [[] for _ in range(6)]`; don't have 6 different similarly named variables.

Comment: @Tim the code dont change the list, dont append nothing

Comment: You have to create a list of tables instead of separate variables for each table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of 6 table variables, use a list of lists, and pass your table number as an index:

```
tables = [[] for _ in range(ntables)]
def serveTable(x):
    print("The menu of the restaurant is:")
    print(foodlist)
    add = input("Which food do you want to add?: ")
    while add != 0:
        for i in range(p):
            if add.lower() == foodlist[i][0]:
                tables[x].append(foodlist[i])
        add = input("Which food do you want to add?: ")
```

Comment: now I have another problem  **NameError: name 'p' is not defined** , I have tried different forms but the variable isn't defined, and i cant use global :D (edit)

Comment: Move your definition of `p` inside the `openFile` function that increments it:  `def openFile():  p = 0 ...`

Comment: I did this, but nothing happens

Comment: You aren't catching the variables that are being returned.  You have `openFile()`, when you should have `foodlist, p = openFile()`

Comment: I had try do something with your tip, but I cant understand where I should put this